Does casting Goodberry consume the mistletoe?
I'm playing a ranger in my next game, and I took the Goodberry spell. I was wondering if I have to buy a sprig of mistletoe every time I want to cast this spell, or do I just need one?

Also, for anyone who's curious, I talked to my DM at lunch, and not only did he let me swap my longbow for a shortbow, but he also let me have an infinite quiver, because I think he was trying to give everyone in the game a personalized magic item. The only caveats are that the arrows can't be sold, only the person who wears the quiver can use the arrows, and the arrows disappear shortly after hitting a surface or the target. After asking the DM, that last point does let me deal 1 additional damage on a hit due to bleeding.

@TheLittlePeace Actually, yes. Thanks for showing me that.

No problem! Just remember, duplicates aren't a bad thing - it's just a tool to help people get to the answer they're looking for.

No, goodberry does not consume the mistletoe
The goodberry spell says (2014 Basic Rules):


(a sprig of mistletoe)


The 2014 Basic Rules in the spellcasting chapter under Components says:

If a spell states that a material component is consumed by the spell, the caster must provide this component for each casting of the spell.

Since goodberry does not say the mistletoe is consumed, it is not, and the same sprig can be used over and over.

Ok, thanks for the help!

And, if you have a component pouch, it is presumed that these little items are kept in there. "A character can use a component pouch or a spellcasting focus in place of the components specified for a spell. But if a cost is indicated for a component, a character must have that specific component before he or she can cast the spell."

No, you need to have just one as material component.
Certain spells need material components, as in this case, and some spells consume such components, but this is specified in the description. See, for example, the Stoneskin spell (emphasis mine):

This spell turns the flesh of a willing creature you touch as hard as stone. Until the spell ends, the target has resistance to nonmagical bludgeoning, piercing, and slashing damage.

(diamond dust worth 100 gp, which the spell consumes)


Check also the rules about material components:

If a spell states that a material component is consumed by the spell, the caster must provide this component for each casting of the spell.

Goodberry does not specify that the sprig of mistletoe  is consumed when you cast it, hence you can keep it and you do not need a new one when you cast this spell.

Thanks for the help! I accepted the other one because I wasn't sure which one to accept, but both were equally helpful.

@Tasi As you prefer, we are saying the same thing, even if I provide an example of a spell that consumes the component.
